# Remove first row after executing Split function in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, csv, split, row, delete-row

How do I remove the first row after executing the following Split function in Excel VBA:

```
Dim testtext As String
Dim csv_rows() As String
csv_rows() = Split(testtext, Chr(10))
```

Reason being that the first row is the column header names which I wish to remove. I tried `csv_rows() = Split(text, Chr(10)) - 1` but it does not seem to work.

Comment: What are you trying accomplishing? How do you want using the resulted array (without its first element)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way, please:

```
csv_rows = Filter(csv_rows, csv_rows(0), False)
```

If it is possible that another line (array element) to be identic with the first one, this way will make it working safer:

```
csv_rows(0) = csv_rows(0) & "####" 'this line can be missing if no any risk that a similar line with the first one exists.
csv_rows = Filter(csv_rows, csv_rows(0), False)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have never heard of `Filter`. For those interested, this is the official doc, sparse but to the point: [VBA.Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filter-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

Comment: @Gustav: It is not well known/used, but I like it. You can do many other interesting things using it. For example, extracting the unique values from a numeric array...

Comment: And something else, there is also another community member (@T.M.) which, besides me, also likes using it and some other unusual ways of using arrays...

Comment: Sure. Seems like a handy tool.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```vb
testtext = "Joe" & vbLf & "Jim" & vbLf & "Kim" & vbLf & "Don"
csv_rows = Split(Split(testtext, vbLf, 2)(1), vbLf)

For i = LBound(csv_rows) To UBound(csv_rows) : ? csv_rows(i) : Next

Jim
Kim
Don
```

Comment: Good combination of resources. In line with that I would have printed the array like this: `Debug.Print Join(csv_rows, vbLf)`. It seems that `?` is valid only in the Immediate Window.

Comment: @EEM: Yes. In code, replace `?` with `Debug.Print`. But this is just to show an example output. There is no info how this will be implemented.